# React Native Can't Pick Up Font's

Tags: ios, reactjs

I followed all the online solutions I still get the same issues. I can't change the fonts.

Error:
Unable to resolve module /assets/fonts/unicode.compacta.ttf from /Users/malo/we-will-name-this-project-later/components/LandingTopUtil.js:

None of these files exist:
unicode.compacta.ttf

```
   const loadFont = async () => {
      await Font.loadAsync({
        'assignedfont': require('/assets/fonts/unicode.compacta.ttf'), // Verify the path
                                    ^
        });
        setFontLoaded(true);
  };
```

> I have looked at how to import the fonts and I checked different solutions but I still get the same issues. The fonts are on the right folder.

```
module.exports = {
project: {
ios: {},
android: {}, // grouped into "project"

# assets: \['./assets/fonts/'\], // stays the same

};
```